# How to view the last index in array of object in row grouping - ag-grid-vue

Tags: vue.js, ag-grid, ag-grid-vue

I Have object that contains array of objects as follow **:**

```
{
  "Id": "123",
  "Name": "usb",
  "email": "123@gmail.com",
  "Config": [
    {
      "config": "config1",
      "field2": "1",
      "field3": "1",
      "field4": "1",
      
    },
    {
      "config": "2",
      "field2": "3",
      "field3": "3",
      "field4": "3",
      
    },
    {
      "field1": "2",
      "field2": "3",
      "field3": "3",
      "field4": "1234568",
      
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to view 'filed4' filed from the last index in config array - 1234568.

This is what i tried to do but i get: [object][object]

[image]

```
this.gridColumns.push({
        headerName: "field4",
        field: "Config",
        width: 60,
        keyCreator: params => params.value[params.value.length-1].field4
      });
```

More code:

```html
setGridColumns() {

      this.gridColumns.push({
        headerName: "Id",
        field: "Id",
        tooltipField: "Id",
        resizable: true,
      });
       this.gridColumns.push({
       headerName: "Name",
       rowGroup: true,
       field: "Name",
       tooltipField: "Name",
       resizable: true,
      });
       this.gridColumns.push({
       headerName: "email",
       field: "email",
       tooltipField: "email",
       resizable: true,
      });
      this.gridColumns.push({
        headerName: "field4",
        field: "Config",
        width: 60,
        keyCreator: params => params.value[params.value.length-1].field4
      });
      return this.gridColumns;
    },
  },
```

Any idea what can be the problem ?

Comment: that exactly what i thought, but it doesn't work:(

Comment: are you using the field Config?

Comment: what do you mean? where?

Comment: Can you add more code please

Comment: `this.gridColumns[this.gridColumns.length - 1].field4`

Comment: hi @tao, didn't understand you answer, can you please explain?

Comment: Tao is saying, Use `this.gridColumns[this.gridColumns.length - 1].field4` instead of `params.value[params.value.length-1].field4` in keyCreator

Comment: thanks, but nothing was changed, still getting [object][object]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`keyCreator` is used with `rowGroup` [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/grouping-complex-objects/). So, please remove `keyCreator` and add `valueGetter` for `Config` field like below:

```js
this.gridColumns.push({
   headerName: "field4",
   field: "Config",
   width: 60,
   valueGetter: params => {
      if (params.data !== undefined) {
         return params.data.Config[params.data.Config.length - 1].field4
      }
   }
});
```